# Changing Document Library Default View

Tags: asp.net, sharepoint, wss

I basically have quite a large site collection with various site and sub sites that all contain their own document libraries. I need to change the default view of each document library to include the following fields:

1. Checked out to.
2. Check in comments.

This is ok as I have written an app that will loop through all existing lists and do this however is there a way I can change the template for a document library so that any future lists that are created will automatically contain these two fields in the their default view?

I am using WSS 3.0.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In WSS 3.0 there is no supported way to modify the out of the box document library

If you don't mind the risk of your change being overwritten by updates then you can modify

```
"C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\12\TEMPLATE\FEATURES\DocumentLibrary\DocLib\schema.xml"
```

In SPF 2010 you can make your changes in a ListAdded event receiver.

Comment: Nice one, I just added "<FieldRef Nam="CheckoutUser"></FieldRef>
    <FieldRef Name="_CheckinComment"></FieldRef>" to the Default view in the Schema.xml as you suggested and it worked like a charm! Thanks!